# UITableViewCell with automatic height and Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I'm creating an UITableView that cell have automatic heigh. Each cell have 3 UILabel that uses Autolayout:
[image: Cell design]

I think i have set all the constraints fine, however I'm experiencing something weird and is that some cell the Event label have more heigh than desired:

[image: Simulator]

Some rows the heigh is fine but some others not, the heigh of the Event lavel could be lower.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // First load table nib
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))

    // Register table cell class from nib
    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "OnlineEventsCell", bundle: bundle)
    tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "onlineEventsCell")
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 59.0; // set to whatever "average" cell height is
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension;
    self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("ActiveEvents", comment: "")
    
    searchBar.delegate=self
    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)

    loadViewData(reloading: false, eventName: nil)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    
    
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set the `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight` in `viewDidLoad()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraints of the cell as shown in [this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJg3A.jpg)

and add this in your code:

```
extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.initTableView()
        
    }

    func initTableView() {
        
        self.tableViewController.delegate = self
        self.tableViewController.dataSource = self
        
        self.tableViewController.register(UINib(nibName: "HotsTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HotsTableViewCell")
        
        self.tableViewController.backgroundColor = .white
        self.tableViewController.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        self.tableViewController.bounces = false
        self.tableViewController.estimatedRowHeight = 600
        self.tableViewController.reloadData()

    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return arrData.count

    }
        
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if arrData.count > 0 {
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HotsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HotsTableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.configuration(example: arrData[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
        
        return UITableViewCell()

    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

}
```

The result will be as shown in [this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK15Z.png)